# Laravel relationship to connect 3 tables to one pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, laravel-5.3

I have an application where users can have different roles for different sites. I created a pivot table `user_access_levels` that contains `id`, `user_id`, `site_id`, `access_level_id`. At first I created a `hasMany` relationship for `UserAccessLevel` in the `User` model and I was able to regulate what a user can access using this

`@if(Auth::user()->userAccessLevels[0]['access_level_id'] == '1')@endif`

but I have realised is a user that it only restricts the user but not the sites.

So I changed the relationship in the `User` model to a `belongsToMany` and now connecting it to the `AccessLevel` model. Laravel is able to pick up the pivot and I can see the multiple access levels a user have. If I do

```
dd(Auth::user()->userAccessLevels);
```

I can see the access levels as follows:

```
    Collection {#254 ▼
        #items: array:3 [▼
            0 => UserAccessLevel {#255 ▶}
            1 => UserAccessLevel {#256 ▶}
            2 => UserAccessLevel {#257 ▶}
        ]
    }
```

What I need is a way to access the specific record that has the current user with the current site. So essentially what I would like is: Assume there are **4** records ***A, B, C, D*** and a user with access **1** can only access records **A and B** ,  a user with access **2** can access **A, B and C**  and a user with access **3** can access all records. Then I have a User named ***John*** who has an access of **1** to ***site I*** and an access of **3** to ***site II***. How can I make sure that if john visits ***site I*** he can only access records A and B but if he visits ***site II*** he can access all records.

The way I am doing it currently, it is using the highest access level for a user for all sites.